# What's wrong with these javascript

Tags: javascript, components

```
var Component = function (config) {
for (property in config) {
this[propety] = config[property]
}
}
var list = Array (
"Item 1",
"Item 2",
"Item 3")；

var instance = Component(id: "XF-254", list: list);
```

It doesn’t work.

Comment: You should use foreach.

Comment: and what exactly should it do??

Answer (score 1):

```
var Component = function (config) {
   for (var property in config) {
     this[propety] = config[property]
   }
}

var list = [
"Item 1",
"Item 2",
"Item 3"]；

var instance = new Component({id: "XF-254", list: list});
```

Comment: Thank you very much..Could you please tell me why you add{} in the last sentence? Or which part of javascript I should learn?  @Khanh TO

Comment: @Sunny: `{}` is a shorthand to create new object, `var obj = {};` is equivalent to `var obj = new Object();`. In your case `{id: "XF-254", list: list}` creates a new object with 2 properties (id:"XF-254" and list:list)

Comment: Can I understand like this: by using component function I create an obj `object(id: "XF-254", list: list)` and then I create another new obj called `instance`...@Khanh TO

Comment: @Sunny: yes, you create an object(id: "XF-254", list: list) and pass that object to the `Component` constructor to create a new object called `instance`.